# Cannot change woocommerce cart page to checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, divi

I am trying to change the cart page to the checkout page so that immediately after purchasing a product, a user is redirected to the checkout page.

I have enabled `Redirect to the cart page after successful addition` and am now in the advanced section trying to change the cart page to be set to checkout, but it is not appearing in the field. How can I fix this?

[image: woocommerce advanced dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change Cart page to Checkout, you must at first remove checkout from "Checkout page" input, next save it and now you can add Checkout page as Cart page.

But, it will probably don't solve your problem. It just change Page (post_id) to another, but it will still be generating Cart, even if name of this page is Checkout.
If you want to "skip" Cart page, probably the easiest solution is to add plugin [WooCommerce Direct Checkout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/) and then select this option.[image]

*Until WooCommerce 3.7 was possible to set the “Checkout” page as both “Cart” and “Checkout” pages. This is not possible any longer, so just follow some other instructions.*